# Create a pie chart with ggplot2 in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the data below and I cant understand why I dont create a pie chart with both `M` and `F` but only one color.

```
setable<-structure(list(Sesso = structure(1:2, levels = c("F", "M"), class = "factor"), 
    Percentage = c(47732L, 36754L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))

library(ggplot2)
# Barplot
bp<- ggplot(setable, aes(x="", y='Percentage', fill="Sesso"))+
  geom_bar(width = 1, stat = "identity")
pie <- bp + coord_polar("y", start=0)
pie
```

Comment: Remove the double quotes around the variable names inside aes

Comment: Try `ggplot(setable, aes(x="", y=Percentage, fill=Sesso))+` the rest you have. You do need to specify some sort of x, which could be `1` or `""` or anything else as a placeholder, but the other variables should be specified without quotes so that ggplot2 interprets them as columns of the source data frame instead of as strings.

Comment: thanks it worked if you post it as an answer

Comment: ggplot(setable, aes(x="", y=Percentage, fill=Sesso)) +  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +  geom_text(aes(label = Percentage,  y = cumsum(Percentage) - Percentage / 2)) + coord_polar("y", start=0) +  theme_void() +  scale_fill_manual(values=c('pink', 'pink2'))